# Sql result object to string in php

Tags: php, sql

Im creating a forum where user can create a poll by giving the question and options. Then I send these to a database using Ajax and PHP and create a table with the name PollTable0. And as new ones get added the number increases s.a. "PollTable1", "PollTable2" etc. I get these numbers by counting the number of tables in the database. My code looks like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['NewPoll'])) {
    $PollArray = $_POST['NewPoll'];
}
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "123", "polldatabase") or die("DIE");

$getnumber = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='polldatabase'";
$number = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE PollTable" . $number . " (" . $PollArray[0] . "VarChar(255))";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);

for ($i = 1; $i < count($PollArray); $i++) {
$target =   "ALTER TABLE PollTable" . $number . " ADD " . $PollArray[i] . " VARCHAR(255)";
mysqli_query($con, $target);
}
echo "Thank you for submitting your poll";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now the problem is $number is an I believe sql result object. Therefore when adding up the string with $number it gives the error:

```
Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string
```

If I am right, is there a way of converting result objects to strings. I have tried strval() and some other methods, which didnt work.
 If I am wrong, what do you think is the reason I am getting this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
$getnumber = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='polldatabase'";
$number = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);
```

to

```
$getnumber = "SELECT COUNT(*) as number FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='polldatabase'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
$number = $result->number;
```

Comment: But you also need to fetch result. Don't you?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek what do you mean?

Comment: Its not giving that error anymore but apparently I still have mistakes... Thank you though

Comment: Undefined property: mysqli_result::$number
This is on the line I added: $number = $result->number;

Answer (score 1):

You should add after line:

```
$number = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);
```

the following lines:

```
$number = mysqli_fetch_row($number);
$number = $number[0];
```

mysqli_query only query database but if you want to fetch results you need to use one of the functions: `mysli_fetch_row`, `mysqli_fetch_array`, `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here

```
$number = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);
```

Mysqli::query will return

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

And you are using `$number` in the next line and hence its issuing the error.

You will need to fetch the result before using it

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Something as

```
$getnumber = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM information_schema.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='polldatabase'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $getnumber);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$number = $data['total'];
```